# RPM Specfile wrong dependancy version resolved during dnf install

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I've created a NodeJS app using NodeJS 18.
I'm creating the .specfile to create an AlmaLinux 8 RPM.

My Requires section looks like this:

```
BuildRequires:         nodejs >= 18.18.2
Requires:              nodejs >= 18.18.2
```

When I try to install my RPM from a fresh and clean AlmaLinux 8 server, it installs nodejs 10 because the NodeJS DNF module enabled by default is the version 10:

```
# dnf module list nodejs
Last metadata expiration check: 0:27:46 ago on Fri 16 Feb 2024 01:11:33 PM UTC.
AlmaLinux 8 - AppStream
Name     Stream   Profiles                                Summary
nodejs   10 [d]   common [d], development, minimal, s2i   Javascript runtime
nodejs   12       common [d], development, minimal, s2i   Javascript runtime
nodejs   14       common [d], development, minimal, s2i   Javascript runtime
nodejs   16       common [d], development, minimal, s2i   Javascript runtime
nodejs   18       common [d], development, minimal, s2i   Javascript runtime
nodejs   20       common [d], development, minimal, s2i   Javascript runtime

Hint: [d]efault, [e]nabled, [x]disabled, [i]nstalled
```

I've found that it's because of the auto requires process:

```
# rpm -q --requires my_app.rpm
/usr/bin/bash
/usr/bin/node
nodejs >= 18.18.2
rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1
rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1
rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1
rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1
```

I've tried to add this line on my .specfile to remove the /usr/bin/node requirment:

```
AutoReqProv:           no
```

But the OS still install NodeJS 10

I've tried to add this line on my .specfile, but same issue:

```
Conflicts:             nodejs < 18
```

Is there a way to get an error + error message like this one:

```
All matches were filtered out by modular filtering for argument: nodejs-18.18.2
Error: Unable to find a match: nodejs-18.18.2
```

Thank you

Comment: I've trying to specify binary version `Requires: /usr/bin/node >= 18` but I've got another error: `Versioned file name not permitted`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution, working for me.

Instead of these lines:

```
BuildRequires:         nodejs >= 18.18.2
Requires:              nodejs >= 18.18.2
```

I've used another "Provides" notation:

```
BuildRequires:         nodejs(abi18)
Requires:              nodejs(abi18)
Conflicts:             nodejs(abi10)
Conflicts:             nodejs(abi12)
Conflicts:             nodejs(abi14)
Conflicts:             nodejs(abi16)
```

And now, I've well my error message:

```
# dnf install my_app.rpm
Last metadata expiration check: 0:51:51 ago on Fri 16 Feb 2024 01:11:33 PM UTC.
Error:
 Problem: package my_app from @commandline requires nodejs(abi18), but none of the providers can be installed
  - conflicting requests
  - package nodejs-1:18.18.2-1.module_el8.8.0+3652+0e111ba0.x86_64 from appstream is filtered out by modular filtering
 (try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
```